# Secure way to query Active Directory without password

Tags: windows, security, active-directory

I am coding an application that needs to query an active directory server with ldap. If I do the bind with user and password it works ok. I do not want the app to have a user and password credentials. Also I cannot enable anonymous binds in AD. How can I create an account that does not require a password but still is secure?

Comment: Two possiblities may be somewhat secure: 1. an IP+ARP(MAC) combination 2. a public-private-key combination. But I do not know if AD supports either one of those.

Comment: When you work on Windows then typically the user is already authenticated against the AD and queries should be possible without password, i.e. using the current authentication.